# Why do spring tests do not reuse the same Context with Embedded Mongo

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, integration-testing

I am doing integration tests and unit tests with spring boot. I made three test classes.

1. ApplicationRunnterTest: to test contextLoads
2. DecisionTreeServiceTest: to test the save function of the service
3. DecisionTreeRepositoryTest: to test the methods of the repo

I added the embdded mongo packages (flapdoodle.embed.mongo). What i have observed is that, when all three  tests are run in this order 1) => 2) => 3)
What happens is when ApplicationRunnerTest loads the context then the second test fails (the service) and the third is success (repository).  The problem is with the context being used or something in the test that fails it says "Error to create bean embedded mongo"

The solution i found is to add the annotation @DirtiesContext() and from what i understand is for each test class, it will make a new context and it worked.

My questions are the following :

1. Why doesnt spring use the same context for all the classes
2. if it does, why there is an ambiguity or an error ?
3. is there a better way instead of @DirtiestContext() since i guess its a lot to load a new context for each test class.

Here are the classes and the erroes.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration()

public class ApplicationRunnerTest {
    @Test
    public void contextLoads(){

    }
}
```

Service class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
//@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class DecisionTreeServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private DecisionTreeRepository decisionTreeRepository;
    @MockBean
    private HistorySupervisionService historySupervisionService;
    @Autowired
    private DecisionTreeService decisionTreeService;
    @Autowired
    private DecisionTreeMapper decisionTreeMapper;


    private DecisionTree[] trees;
    @Before
    public void init() throws IOException {
        // get test data
        JacksonMapper jacksonMapper = new JacksonMapper();
        trees =  jacksonMapper.loadJsonFileToObject("src/test/java/com/almerys/cpm/back/utils/decisionTree/decisionTreeObject",
                DecisionTree[].class
        );
        //clear databse first
        this.decisionTreeRepository.deleteAll();
        // save object 2 and object 3
        this.decisionTreeRepository.save(trees[1]);
        this.decisionTreeRepository.save(trees[2]);
    }

    @Test
    public void saveTest(){
        // TEST CREATE SCENARIO
        DecisionTreeDTO decisionTree = this.decisionTreeMapper.toDto(trees[0]);
        DecisionTree savedDecisionTree = trees[0];
        savedDecisionTree.setId("1");
        savedDecisionTree.setInternalId(4);
//        Mockito.when(decisionTreeRepository.findFirstByOrderByInternalIdDesc()).thenReturn(Optional.of(trees[2]));
//        Mockito.when(decisionTreeRepository.save(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(savedDecisionTree);
        Mockito.when(historySupervisionService.getLastVersionByContext(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("13.0");
        DecisionTreeDTO createdDecisionTree= decisionTreeService.save(decisionTree);
        assertThat(createdDecisionTree).isNotNull();
        assertThat(createdDecisionTree.getInternalId()).isEqualTo(4);
        assertThat(createdDecisionTree.getFactoryVersion()).contains("13.1");

        // TEST UPDATE SCENARIO

    }
```

Repo Class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataMongoTest

public class DecisionTreeRepositoryTest{
    @Autowired
    private DecisionTreeRepository decisionTreeRepository;


    private void initData() throws IOException {
        //clean embedded database first.
        this.decisionTreeRepository.deleteAll();
        // retrieve data from json
        JacksonMapper jacksonMapper = new JacksonMapper();
        DecisionTree[] createDecisionTree=  jacksonMapper.loadJsonFileToObject("src/test/java/com/almerys/cpm/back/utils/decisionTree/decisionTreeObject",
                DecisionTree[].class
                );
        // persist data
        Arrays.stream(createDecisionTree).forEach(tree-> this.decisionTreeRepository.save(tree));

    }

    @Before
    public void init() throws IOException {
        this.initData();
    }


    @Test
    public void findByFactoryCategoryInternalId(){
        DecisionTree decisionTree = this.decisionTreeRepository.findByFactoryCategoryInternalIdAndFactoryVersion(1,"11.0");
        assertThat(decisionTree).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

Error

```
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDbFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDbFactoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedMongoServer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/embedded/EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Could not start process: <EOF>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesnt spring use the same context for all the classes

The simple answer is: because one of the test uses `@MockBean`.

When using mock bean, you're asking Spring to replace the original bean instance with a mock. Obviously, other beans might depend on that bean, it might be involved in their initialization etc., so any previously created context needs to be scrapped in order for the test environment to be reliable.

Also, do all the test reside in the same package? If not, I think the consequence of using `@ContextConfiguration` will be that only components residing in the same package and sub-packages are going to be picked up. This implies the test context for each of the tests will **not** be the same, so obviously the test context cannot be reused.

> why there is an ambiguity or an error ?

Hard to say without looking at the actual configuration, but my guess would be the embedded Mongo doesn't cleanup after itself properly.